# Dash Plotly Shut Up Warnings/Errors

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, warnings, dashboard, plotly-dash

I Created a very simple Dash Plotly code with Python.

- The user drags an input file (any excel file with string column names should do).
- Selects the column names he needs from th dropdowns for x and y axis.
- A simple graph appears.

However before the user drags the input file, I keep having those errors relative to the fact that, until the users uploads anything, the code sees "None".

Is there anything I can do to shut it up?

The code is the following:

```
import base64
import datetime
import io
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

colors = {"graphBackground": "#F5F5F5", "background": "#ffffff", "text": "#000000"}

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
            style={
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "60px",
                "lineHeight": "60px",
                "borderWidth": "1px",
                "borderStyle": "dashed",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "textAlign": "center",
                "margin": "10px",
            },
            # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
            multiple=True,
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='x_dropdown', 
            options = [],
            placeholder="X Axis - Please Select Column"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='y_dropdown', 
            options = [],
            placeholder="Y Axis - Please Select Column"),
        dcc.Graph(id="Mygraph"),
        html.Div(id="output-data-upload"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('Mygraph', 'figure'), [
Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
Input('upload-data', 'filename'),
Input('x_dropdown','value'),
Input('y_dropdown','value')
])



def update_graph(contents, filename, x_dropdown, y_dropdown):
    x = []
    y = []
    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        x_dropdown = str(x_dropdown)
        y_dropdown = str(y_dropdown)
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        x=df[x_dropdown]
        y=df[y_dropdown]
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Bar(
                x=x, 
                y=y)
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            plot_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"],
            paper_bgcolor=colors["graphBackground"]
        ))
    return fig


def parse_data(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(",")

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if "csv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV or TXT file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")))
        elif "xls" in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif "txt" or "tsv" in filename:
            # Assume that the user upl, delimiter = r'\s+'oaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode("utf-8")), delimiter=r"\s+")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div(["There was an error processing this file."])

    return df

@app.callback(
    Output("output-data-upload", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), 
     Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)


def update_table(contents, filename):
    table = html.Div()

    if contents:
        contents = contents[0]
        filename = filename[0]
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        table = html.Div(
            [
                html.Hr(),
                html.H5(filename),
                html.Hr(),
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    data=df.to_dict("rows"),
                    columns=[{"name": str(i), "id": str(i)} for i in df.columns],
                ),
                html.Hr(),
                html.Div(""),
            ]
        )

    return table

# update x_dropdown
@app.callback(Output('x_dropdown', 'options'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])

def update_x_dropdown(contents, filename):
    contents = contents[0]
    filename = filename[0]
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
        if df is not None:
            return [ {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in columns ]
        else:
            return []
    else:
        return []
    
# update y_dropdown
@app.callback(Output('y_dropdown', 'options'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])

def update_y_dropdown(contents, filename):
    contents = contents[0]
    filename = filename[0]
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_data(contents, filename)
        columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
        if df is not None:
            return [ {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in columns ]
        else:
            return []
    else:
        return []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea here:

```py
def update_y_dropdown(contents, filename):
    contents = contents[0]
    filename = filename[0]
    if contents is not None:
        # do stuff
```

Just have each callback checking for actual values before trying to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should check if contents is not none at the beginning.

Secondly, Duplicate code is bad practice. **update_x_dropdown** and **update_y_dropdown** are identical methods ===> keep only one.

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('x_dropdown', 'options'),
     Output('y_dropdown', 'options')],
    [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
     Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_dropdown(contents, filename):
    if not contents or not filename:
        return [], []
    contents = contents[0]
    filename = filename[0]
    df = parse_data(contents, filename)
    columns = df.columns.values.tolist()
    if df is not None:
        out = [{'label': x, 'value': x} for x in columns]
        return out, out
    else:
        return [], []
```